# Laravel Model Factories with Tests

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm trying to create a team and then add that team to a game and then add that game to the event, however, when the game is created it auto generates an event to attach to the event. In normal circumstances this is fine but because I'm testing the team's joined at compared to the event their first game is on then I need to create an event with a specific date. I can't create the event first because the game has to be created first to be able to add it to it.

Does anyone have a suggestion on correcting my logic so that I can get a game and event created correctly?

I don't know what I should need to do for this edge case.

```
/** @test */
public function a_team_with_a_game_after_they_started_the_season_cannot_have_their_joined_at_date_after_their_first_match()
{
    $team = factory(Team::class)->create(['joined_at' => '2017-10-08']);

    $game = GameFactory::create([], [$team]);
    $event = EventFactory::create(['date' => '2017-10-09'], null, $game);

    $validator = new BeforeFirstGameDate($team);

    $this->assertFalse($validator->passes('joined_at', '2017-10-10'));
    $this->assertEquals('The joined at date cannot be AFTER the team\'s first game.', $validator->message());
}

Factories

<?php

use App\Models\Game;
use App\Models\Team;

class GameFactory
{
    public static function create($overrides = [], $teams = [])
    {
        $match = factory(Game::class)->create($overrides);

        self::addTeamsForGame($teams, $game);

        return $game;
    }

     /**
     * @param $teams
     * @param $game
     */
    public static function addTeamsForGame($teams, $game)
    {
        $teamsForGame = [];

        $numberOfTeamsToAdd = $numberOfTeams - count($teams);

        if ($numberOfTeamsToAdd) {
            $teamsForMatch = factory(Team::class, $numberOfTeamsToAdd)->create();
            array_push($teams, $teamsForGame);
        } else {
            array_push($teams, $teamsForGame);
        }

        $match->addTeams($teamsForGame);
    }
}


<?php

use App\Models\Event;

class EventFactory
{
    public static function create($overrides = [], $totalNumberOfGames = 8, $games = [])
    {
        $event = factory(Event::class)->create($overrides);

        $numberOfGamesToAdd = $totalNumberOfGames - count($games);
        $gameToStartAt = count($games) + 1;

        foreach (array_wrap($games) as $game) {
            $game->addToEvent($event);
        }

        for ($gameNumber = $gameToStartAt; $gameNumber <= $numberOfGamesToAdd; $gameNumber++) {
            GameFactory::create(['event_id' => $event->id, 'game_number' => $gameNumber]);
        }

        return $event;
    }
}


$factory->define(App\Models\Game::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $order = 1;
    return [
        'event_id' => function () {
            return factory(App\Models\Event::class)->create()->id;
        },
        'game_number' => $order++,

    ];  
});

$factory->define(App\Models\Event::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    $name = $faker->sentence;
    return [
        'name' => $name,
        'slug' => str_slug($name),
        'date' => $faker->dateTimeBetween('-10 years'),
    ];
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: The source code shown below is based on some assumptions since the specific implementation of models like for instance `Event`, `Game` and `Team` were not given in the original question. Consider adding a Git repository containing the sources to the question to get more specific answers that reflects your implementation in more detail.

First, some general remarks to tests:

- unit tests (in case the code show above is one, with the focus on **unit**) should only test one specific aspect of your domain layer - thus, to ensure that `BeforeFirstGameDate` is behaving correctly but not testing a combination of possible involved services (database) or factories for object reconstitution - the techniques to be used are "mocks" or "prophecies"
- integration tests (that's how the code above looks like) should on the other hand be tested with the real implementation (no "mocks" nor "prophecies" if possible), but on a faked/provided scenario - means if you want to test the whole application of factories, models and validators you should provide a complete testing scenario in the database for instance and perform your tests based on these

That being said and putting the focus more on the **unit** part in "unit test" your tests might look like - focussing on testing single, separated units and not a combination of them:

```
/** @test */
public function eventIsCreated()
{
  ...
  static::assertSame($expectedEvent, EventFactory::create(...));
}
/** @test */
public function teamIsCreated()
{
  ...
  static::assertSame($expectedTeam, TeamFactory::create(...));
}
/** @test */
public function gameIsCreated()
{
  ...
  static::assertSame($expectedGame, GameFactory::create(...));
}
/** @test */
public function beforeFirstGameDateValidatorRejectsLateApplications()
{
  ...
}
```

The mentioned test case for `BeforeFirstGameDate` validation might just look like the following then, using prophecies - the instance to be tested is named as `$subject` to make it clear, what's the subject to be tested (as common best practice in writing tests):

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function beforeFirstGameDateValidatorRejectsLateApplications()
{
    $event = $this->prophesize(Event::class);
    $game = $this->prophesize(Game::class);
    $team = $this->prophesize(Team::class);

    $event->getGames()->willReturn([$game->reveal()]);
    $game->getTeams()->willReturn([$team->reveal()]);
    $team->get('joined_at')->willReturn('2017-10-08');

    $subject = new BeforeFirstGameDate($team->reveal());

    static::assertFalse(
        $subject->passes('joined_at', '2017-10-10')
    );
}
```

This way, your `Event`, `Game` and `Team` models don't rely on any factory implementation anymore, but simulate properties and behavior using prophecies. Thus, in case factories get changed or refactored you only have to adjust those tests that assert object reconsitution - the mentioned `beforeFirstGameDateValidatorRejectsLateApplications` can be skipped since it does not have a hard dependency on these factories for instance.

*As mentioned in the beginning the methods and properties for `Event`, `Game` and `Team` are just assumptions since the real implementation was unknown at the time of writing this answer.*

References:

- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.prophecy
- https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy#how-to-use-it

Answer (score 2):

You should use the same logic as when you are doing this in your application :

• Create an event

• Add a game to the event

• Add a team to the game

If you need to test your date, then just edit them after :)

Comment: If I create the event first then I wouldn't have the game created to pass to it to then add it to the event.

Comment: event is created, teams are assigned to a game that is then assigned to an event.

Comment: when is created the game ?

Comment: On a form on another page.

Comment: yes, but WHEN ? after or before an event is created ? Does they are even related when they are create ?

take a pen and a sheet of paper, and write down the step of your process, then juste replicate them, step by step